# htaccess not working on my VPS with cpanel

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel

I have a website which was on a VPS with directadmin Control Panel, but I have just moved to another VPS with Cpanel. It used to work when it wan on the old VPS but in the new one I can’t make it work..!!

My script is CodeIgniter script and in this script this url:

```
www.mydomain.com/index.php/news
```

should be converted to:

```
www.mydomain.com/news
```

But after using htaccess, I can open the main page (which is index.php) greatly but when I want to go to www.mydomain.com/news (this should be defined as www.mydomain.com/index.php/news by htacces ) it shows me the main page. I have installed CodeIgniter (the framework I am using for my script) in the public_html folder (which is under home/user).

I have full admin access to my VPS, WHM/Cpanel and I can make any changes.

this is the .htaccess that was working for me in my old VPS:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule> 

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I have just found that by converting this line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

to this one:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [R]
```

means changing flag [L] to [R], it works, but it just converts **www.domain.com/news** to **www.domain.com/index.php/news** and shows in the addressbar and this not what I want.

Do you have any solution?! Should I change any configuration on Cpanel?!

Comment: 1) Maybe you have a real file or folder called `news`? 2) to do a simple debugging: alter your rule to rewrite to `echo.php` file, create one and put this inside: `<?php phpinfo(INFO_VARIABLES);` There look for value of `_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` and `_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` -- it may give you some hints. Otheriwse -- enable rewrite debugging (`RewriteLog` & `RewriteLevel 9`) and see what log says.

Comment: Thanks,
_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] is /news
_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] is no value
these are same as the old VPS, and seems to work correctly, the only difference is in new VPS I also have _ENV["REQUEST_URI"] and _ENV["QUERY_STRING"] values. What are these?!

Comment: `_ENV` ... I do not have them on my setup -- you may run PHP differently (I'm running it as Apache module, not CGI or FastCGI which may be on your setup). In any case -- so far it look good for me. Can you also check the value of `_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]`. If rewrite works fine then it should be `/echo.php/news` (when accessing `domain.com/news`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Hope it works on your CodeIgniter install, I had the same problem and this solved it.